# @media query not responding for tablet and desktop view

Tags: html, css

css code.

```
               /* media query for tablet */
               @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
               .cta {
               font-size: 2.5rem;
               padding: 20px 60px;
               }
               h1 .section-title {
               font-size: 6rem;
               }

               /* hero section */
               #hero h1 {
               font-size: 7rem;
               }
               /* end of hero section */

               /* service section */
               #services .service-bottom .services-item {
               flex-basis: 45%;
               margin: 2.5%;
               }
               /* end of service section */
               }
               /* end of media query for tablet */

               /* media query for desktop */
               @media only screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
               /* header */
               #header .hamburger {
                  display: none;
               }
               /* end of header */
               }
               /* end of media query for desktop */
```

html code

```
                 !DOCTYPE html>
                 <html lang="en">
                 <head>
                 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
                  <title>My Website</title>
                 </head>
<body>
<!-- header section -->
<section id="header">
  <div class="header container">
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <div class="brand">
        <a href="#hero">
          <h1>HOME OF TECHNOLOGY.</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-list">
        <div class="hamburger"><div class="bar"></div></div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" data-after="Home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-after="Services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-after="Projects">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-after="About us">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-after="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- end of header section -->
```

My media query for tablet and desktop is not responding though I have no code errors in vscode. I designed phone version first, then media query for tablet and lastly media query for desktop and both are not responding. My media query is below the keyframes.

Comment: Have you tried only using "@media only screen"?

Comment: @MannyAlvarado yes there is no change and am getting code errors if I try -media only screen.

Comment: Where is the rest of the html?

Comment: @Chanckjh let me update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look for these sizes

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/

Comment: This kinda has helped bring responsiveness. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){

}

Comment: There is no change still.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).